# finding last column name when two columns have max value in one row python

Tags: python, dataframe, max

This is my data frame

```
  x y z

0 1 0 0

1 1 0 1

2 0 0 1

3 0 1 1

4 1 1 0
```

When i am using df.idxmax(axis=1)

The Output i am getting is

```
x

x

z

y

x
```

My desired output is

```
x

z

z

z

y
```

Please help me in finding the column name of max row when two rows contains max value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about taking vertical symmetry and then idxmax, i.e.,

```
df.iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)
```

```
0    x
1    z
2    z
3    z
4    y
```

so the `df.iloc[:, ::-1]` part is

```
   z  y  x
0  0  0  1
1  1  0  1
2  1  0  0
3  1  1  0
4  0  1  1
```

it's from z to x now

Another way with reindexing might be more clear in giving away the intent:

```
df.reindex(columns=df.columns[::-1]).idxmax(axis=1)
```

```
0    x
1    z
2    z
3    z
4    y
```

as above.

Comment: Thanks! That worked but if there are more columns which are not related to this part then can we do it?

Comment: @sudarshanmishra hi, if you can give an example for it in your question by editing it, maybe we can do it.

Comment: can't you just select those columns and do the same? for example ```df[['x','y','z']].iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)```

Comment: Yes @sophocles I can actually do that

Comment: @Neither Thanks but what i was asking was really naive, got my answer so thanks for that

Comment: @sudarshanmishra okay i'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a map or apply or transform and call a function to produce the desired results per row?

```
Df[“result”]=Df.map(mydictionary)

Mydictionary returns x or y or z
```

Comment: But that will take more time using map or apply if the datarame is big.